# Why does my depth render look so washed out despite the model having lots of depth?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

So I made a terrain map, and I'm trying to render it as a heightmap. Here is my setup so far;

[image: compositing]

Now heres the actual terrain itself;

[image: terrain mesh]

Now my completed heightmap;

[image]

I can clearly tell that is not giving me all the depth detail there. How can I make it so it is actually an accurate heightmap? Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think you can “clearly tell”? Remember, non colour data is not a colour, and therefore the values may deceive you. A distance will not change in a similar manner to a series of exposure values. Right click on the image and sample the values.

Answer (score 0):

The "Depth"-pass uses the camera clipping range as bounds for its values.

So if your clipping range is much larger than the Z-dimension of your terrain, it will only occupy a small range of all possible values. 
As all possible values are mapped to a value between 0 and 255 (at least on your screen, depending on your output format bitdepth you may get a finer resolution), you won't see much in your heightmap unless the camera range and the dimensions of your scene match.